# How can I read the terminal input on a tty device before a newline arrives?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, tty

I am reading a serial device using embedded linux (angstrom) using open(), tcget/setattr(), read().  I can read and write data just fine.  However, the device I am reading displays a prompt that is not terminated with a newline.  This means I can't read the prompt until after I cause the device to send some other output that has a newline at the end.  Basically, I know the prompt string ("COM3>") is sitting in the tty buffer waiting for the device to send a newline.  read() won't access the "COM3>" prompt string until the newline arrives.  Is there any way to change the force read() to get the data in the buffer before the newline arrives?

Thanks

Comment: Terminal output is never line buffered at the tty driver level. I suspect you're using stdio and that's where the buffering is happening. Either use low-level io (`write`) or `fflush` or `setbuf` to disable buffering.

Comment: @R.: That not true.  In canonical mode, which is the default, a terminal device is line-buffered.

Comment: **Input** is line-buffered in canonical mode. Output is not. Now that you mention it though, OP's question is really unclear as to which part (input or output) is not working as expected...

Comment: @R.: The talk of `read()` implies to me that the OPs code is reading from the serial device when the problem occurs.

Comment: It is the input that I am concerned about.  I am not using stdio such as fread() or fgets().  I am using read().  I open the device using: `open("/dev/ttyAT0", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY);`  I understand there are ways to deal with buffering using tcgetattr() but nothing I have tried has work.  The driver seems to be line-buffering the input and not letting read() access anything until the newline arrives.

Answer (score 4):

In canonical mode, which is the default, input is line-buffered.

What you probably want is to set the terminal into "raw" mode with `cfmakeraw()`, which will (among other things) disable canonical mode.

See the `tcsetattr()` man page for more information.

Comment: I remember doing this with an ioctl() call, which is even lower level.

Comment: @Joshua: Well, `cfmakeraw()` is just a helper function that modifies a `struct termios`, you still have to pass a pointer to that struct to the kernel to make it take effect.  You can either do that with the `TCSETS` `ioctl()` or with `tcsetattr()` - the latter is just a convenience wrapper around the former.

Comment: Note that `cfmakeraw` also does not seem to be a standardized function, although it's widely supported..

Comment: cfmakeraw() looks promising.  I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: I tried cfmakeraw() and it looks like that did the trick.  The device I am reading is quirky for other reasons, but cfmakeraw() allowed me to read before the newline arrived.

Answer (score -1):

One of the benefits of C is that there's a hundred ways to do anything.

I wouldn't use ioctl if it were I.

A simple cMyChar = getc(STDIN) would do nicely.

Comment: As a clarification, I should not have said "Terminal" in the question.    I am not trying to read the STDIN.  I am trying to read another tty device.