# Stopwatch program in standard C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program of a stopwatch using this Standard C-Free 5.0. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

char button;
int minutes=0, seconds=0, millisec=0;

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        reset:
        button = '\0';
        int minutes=0, seconds=0, millisec=0;
        printf("  %d :  %d :  %d ", minutes, seconds, millisec);
        system("cls");
        if(button == 'a')
        {
            while(1)
            {
                cont:
                button = '\0';
                Sleep(10);
                millisec++;
                if(millisec == 100)
                {
                    millisec = 0;
                    seconds++;
                    if(seconds == 60)
                    {
                        seconds = 0;
                        minutes++;
                    }
                }
                printf("  %d :  %d :  %d ", minutes, seconds, millisec);
                system("cls");
                if(button == 's')
                {
                    while(1)
                    {
                        button = '\0';
                        printf("  %d :  %d :  %d ", minutes, seconds, millisec);
                        system("cls");
                        if(button == 'a')
                        {
                            goto cont;
                        }
                        if(button == 'd')
                        {
                            goto reset;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to start the stopwatch with a pressed of button 'a' but it wouldn't work. Using scanf() will pause the whole program. Is there a way to detect a button being pressed and continue the stopwatch program? I mean without pausing the program especially the pressing 's' to stop and pressing 'a' again to continue, while displaying the timer at all times.

Comment: [C-Free](http://www.programarts.com/cfree_en/index.htm) is an IDE, not a compiler.  Can you tell us what compiler you're using it with?  because in some of the supported compiler's libraries there will be functions like `kbhit()` available.

Answer (score 3):

This should help [`_kbhit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and it's important to use `_getch()` after it.

```
#include <conio.h>

//...

int key;
while (1)
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        key = _getch();

        if (key == 'a')
            printf("You pressed 'a'\n");
        else if (key == 'd')
            printf("You pressed 'd'\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @JitzuZu when you get answer you're satisfied with, it's important for how Stack Overflow works, that you accept the answer (click that check mark at the upper left corner of an answer). You haven't accepted any answer to any of your questions, so go and check them too, and accept if they are answered.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `system("cls");`, this is probably on dos / Windows command prompt. You can try to see if [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is supported by your compiler.

If it is, [`kbhit()` or `_kbhit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (link to MSDN, you should check docs of your compiler's libraries for most accurate reference) seems to be what you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system problem not C. In general, your hosting system provide buffering to inputs, so when you press a key, it is not delivered at that time to your program, it is buffered until some condition occurs (basically, an end-of-line is pressed).

Under Windows there is different calls you should make to get a keypress.

Under Unix, you should put your tty in non-canonical mode (there is a set of magic calls to `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr`).

See that [one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222231/how-can-i-read-the-terminal-input-on-a-tty-device-before-a-newline-arrives/9222520#9222520)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<windows.h>
main()
{
int choice, h,m,s; h=0; m=0; s=0; //--variable declaration--//
char p= 'p';
printf("Press 1 to start the timer\nPress 2 to exit\n");
printf("\nEnter your choice\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
switch(choice) //--switch case --//
{
case 1:
{
while(1) //--while condition is true//
{
if(s>59) //--if seconds(s) is > 59--//
{
m=m+1; //--increment minute by 1--//
s=0;
}
if(m>59) //--if minutes(s) is > 59--//
{
h=h+1; //--increment hour by 1--//
m=0;
}
if(h>11) //--if hour(h) is > 11--//
{
h=0; //-Hour to 0--//
m=0;
s=0;
}
Sleep(1000); //--inbuilt function for 1sec delay--//
s=s+1;
system("cls"); //--Clear screen--//
printf("DIGITAL CLOCK");
printf("\n\nHOUR:MINUTE:SECOND");
printf("\n\n%d:%d:%d",h,m,s); //--Print time--//
printf("\n\nTo pause : press P\n");
if(kbhit()) //--Check if any button is pressed on keyboard--//
{
if(p==getch()) //--Check if P is pressed--//
{
system("pause"); //--Inbuilt function for pause and resume--//
}
}
}
break;
}
case 2:
exit(0); //--Exit --//
default:
{
printf("Wrong Choice");
}
}
getch(); //--Holding the screen--//
return 0;
}
```